# Android: stack overflow error on EditText TextChangedListener

Tags: android, android-edittext, stack-overflow

I get the StackOverflow error running this particular code:

```
litera.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
                String ghici = litera.getText().toString();
                System.out.println(ghici);
                litera.setText("");
            }

        });
```

I commented each line at a time and I found out that the culprit is the litera.setText(""); line, the others work normally. I've used it before and it baffles me why a particularly simple instruction causes such a bad error... The rest of the error messages are about "android.view.ViewGroup.addFocusables(ViewGroup.java:637)" and others, but I doubt they are conclusive.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

u have to use this way

```
 litera.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            String strEnteredVal = litera.getText().toString();
            if(!strEnteredVal.equals("")){
            System.out.println(strEnteredVal);
            litera.setText("");
            }
        }

    });
```

Comment: Amazingly, this worked! I don't get the difference from the code above (how does comparing the string to "" differ from comparing "" with the string?), but it did the trick Thank you! :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're setting the `TextView`'s text from within the same `TextView`'s `TextWatcher`, then you've set up an infinite loop, which is causing a `StackOverflowException`.

Comment: That sounds good. So how can I make it to clear the EditText after each character entered? i e I want to read and process one character at a time (for a hangman game). Thanks!

Comment: Then use [`setFilters()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setFilters(android.text.InputFilter[])) instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are having this problem because you are changing the text from your onChange listener.  What happens is the user changes the text, which invokes your `onTextChange` method, which in turn changes the text and that again invokes `onTextChange` listener - and so on.  If you are required to change the text from the listener, then you need to somehow ignore text changes from your code and only handle the ones from the user.  For example, you can try something like this:

```
litera.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {}
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after){}
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count){
            if(count > 0) {
                String ghici = litera.getText().toString();
                System.out.println(ghici);
                litera.setText("");
            }
        }
    });
```

this will ignore all changes where the edittext content has been erased (by your code).

Comment: It does work now, but it doesn't erase my EditText like I want to. I want to read and process one character at a time for a hangman game, so I need it to either erase the EditText after every input, or only allow one character inputs. How can I do that?

Comment: Your edit with if(!"".equals(s)) instead of if(before>0) makes the stack overflow again :(

Comment: Hm... try with `if(count > 0)`  The idea is to ignore setting the text to empty

Comment: Khan managed to solve it. Thank you for your time anyway, I much appreciate your contribution!

Answer (score 0):

you are calling settext method inside the onTextChanged listener. this would cause the listener to fire the onTextChanged method again and again. this is causing the stackOverflow error